# would like to run a third party executable on Azure VM

Tags: ffmpeg, executable, azure-virtual-machine, azure-security

I would like to run ffmpeg.exe and process media files on Azure VM. Do I need to add the exe anywhere in the VM settings? I have copied ffmpeg.exe to Azure VM and trying to run a command, but ffmpeg.exe --help also not returning anything, no error either. Do I have to whitelist the .exe in order to run it on Azure VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using a Linux image then one way would be directly installing the `ffmpeg` using package manager instead of the `.exe` file. Just run the following commands in the vm

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

[image]

- Now if you have a windows server just make sure that you are in the folder where the `ffmpeg.exe` is located. If you want to run the `ffmpeg` anywhere on the server you will have to install you can refer this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/614297/installing-ffmpeg-for-windows-server-2012#:%7E:text=FFmpeg%20is%20a,needs%20%3Effmpeg%20-arguments) by  the user - [peanut_butter](https://superuser.com/users/232590/peanut-butter)